# Odd white-space: nowrap; behaviour in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css

When using `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` in iOS, the parent container is expanded to match the width of the overflown text. The parent containers `width` is set to `100%` the width of `body`.

In all other browsers, the parent container remains within the confines of body.

Setting a fixed width on the container solves the issue, but is not an option as it has to be 100% the width of the parent element.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7g8m5Ljr/1/) is a JSFiddle illustrating the issue

Thanks.